# covering map $\mathbb{R}^2 - $2 points $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - $ 1 points?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a covering map $\mathbb{R}^2 - $2 points $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - $ 1 points?

wanted to double check if my reasoning below is correct.

$\mathbb{R}^2 - $2 points deformation retracts to a surface with genus $2$ while $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - $ 1 deformation retracts to a surface of genus $1$. Thus, there is no such covering map.

Answer (score 3):

You have a good idea, but I think there are still some gaps. You have to clarify why a potential covering map restricted to your specific retract of $B = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{point\}$ gives your specific retract of $E = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{two \phantom{x} points\}$.

I suggest to proceed as follows. Assume there is covering map $p : E \to B$. We know that $p_* : \pi_1(E) \to \pi_1(B)$ is injective. But we have $B \simeq S^1$ and $E \simeq S^1 \vee S^1$, thus $\pi_1(B) = \mathbb Z$ and $\pi_1(E) = \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$. This prevents the existence of an injective homomorphism as required.